# How can I package and distribute Python projects with dependencies that require driver installations?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am creating a Python package which requires Selenium as a dependency. To get Selenium to work locally, I need to install a Chrome/Firefox Driver prior to utilizing it. I am wondering if there is a way to install this driver with my package when installed with pip so that my package can be used right after installing without needing to go through additional steps of driver installation?

Comment: You can add this to the documentation for the Python package, but how is pip supposed to know the version of the driver, the operating system and any other dependencies that are independent of your package or python?

Comment: Shouldn't it be as easy as to include it in your repository and use git clone when you want to "install it".

Comment: I just added it to my git repo...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use https://pypi.org/project/webdriver-manager/ library and setup driver dependency programmatically at run time.

```
pip install webdriver-manager
```

For example, below python line will automatically install chromedriver and will set the enviorment path.

```py
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
```

Similarly, you can configure other driver as well.

**Work offline**

If you want your python package to work with out run time dependency and you need to pack driver with your package. Then you can use below code to download and get the download path. Then you can move the driver to your resource and pack it programmatically.

```py
executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install()
```

Answer (score 1):

I reckon it is not wise to add the drivers as part of your package, because the end users  may update the browser and it requires a new version of the driver, at this point you have to roll out an update to your package.

Having said that, I dont know what your package does, but if you want to add some binary data with your package and use it without needing an external package, you could try the below approach.

The PostInstallCommand will run after install.

**setup.py**

```
import pkg_resources
from setuptools import setup
from setuptools.command.install import install


class PostInstallCommand(install):
    def run(self):
        driver = pkg_resources.resource_filename(__name__, 'geckodriver.exe')
        # do whatever you want to do with your driver
        install.run(self)


setup(
   name='mypackage',
   version='1.0',
   packages=['mypackage'],
   package_data = {'mypackage': ['drivers/*']},
   description='Test',
   author='Batman',
   author_email='batman@superheroes.com',
   install_requires=['selenium>=3.14.1'],
   cmdclass={'install': PostInstallCommand}
)
```

Comment: Thanks! Ultimately I decided to just include the driver installation as part of the setup instructions in the ReadMe.md file for this reason.